# Missing /var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock file

Tags: mysql, linux, unix, amazon-ec2

I'm trying to access mysql and when I run the mysql command, I get the following.

> [root@ip-10-229-65-166
>   tpdatabase-1.8.0.28356]# mysql
>
> ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to
>   local MySQL server through socket
>   '/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock' (2)

Doing this returns nothing

> [root@ip-10-229-65-166 mysqld]# find
>   -name mysql*
>
> [root@ip-10-229-65-166 mysqld]#
>   /etc/init.d/mysql stop
>   -bash: /etc/init.d/mysql: No such file or directory
>
> [root@ip-10-229-65-173
>   tpdatabase-1.8.0.28356]# mysql_config
>   |grep -- --socket
>
> --socket         [/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock]

Maybe a permissions problem?

I do have mysql installed using **yum install mysql**

I'm running CentOS 5.4 on a Amazon EC2 Cloud Instance

Answer (score 33):

You need to install the server package:

```
sudo yum install mysql-server
```

After installation, you have to start the service:

```
sudo service mysqld start
```

Comment: And then maybe `chkconfig mysqld on`

Comment: I already did that but in ubuntu, and it says mariadb is installed?

Answer (score 14):

```
rm -rvf /var/lib/mysql/ib_logfile*
touch /var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock
touch /var/lib/mysql/mysql.pid
chown -R mysql:mysql /var/lib/mysql
systemctl restart mysql
```

try this and check the permission of both /var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock and /tmp

Comment: The only answer that worked for me after hours of search. I even did a fresh installation of mysql-server on my Centos machine.

Answer (score 7):

We faced a similar problem in my office setup with the same OS. The actual thing that was happening was low space on the server. It is quite strange, but i believe if the server gets full the files cannot be loaded or of some other resort. Please check to be sure the space on the server is enough else you have to try removing the installed mysql and reinstall. Best of luck.

Answer (score 4):

just search for mysqld, this is the server daemon:

```
find / | grep mysqld
```

If you found it, the server package may be correctly installed but without initd scripts. For testing, you may start the mysql server by hand executing the above file.

Answer (score 1):

mysql might have been packaged separately as client and server. Check your package repositories to make sure that the server has been installed. The `mysql` package might only be the client. Check if there's a package called `mysql-server` or something similar. Check the list of files installed by the `mysql` package to see if it actually installs the server.

If the files are not even there, it's not a permissions problem. Also, you're running as root.

Comment: Checked that it's installed                                    Package mysql-server-5.0.77-4.el5_5.5.i386 already installed and latest version
Nothing to do

Comment: What are the files that that package installed?

Comment: It would be too long to paste specific files here but I have mysql, mysql-devel and mysql-server packages installed.

Comment: Basically, what I'm asking you to do is to find out where the server files are installed and if the "normal" init scripts are not, to find out which package contains them and install those.

Comment: Seem's like there is not a init.d script for mysql.  Sorry for the confusion, i'm just having a hard time trying to figure out what's wrong.  I should possibly try downloading a mysql rpm.

Comment: `yum` downloads and installs the rpm.

Answer (score 0):

I recently encountered this problem after an upgrade on Ubuntu 18.04. The solution here solved it https://serverfault.com/a/957723/439448.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have privileges to access the /var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock file. And if you still get the error, create a default my.cnf file with

```
[client]
socket = /path/to/mysql/data/mysql.sock
[mysqld]
server-id = 2
socket = /path/to/mysql/data/mysql.sock
port = 4000 #any port you wish
basedir = /path/to/mysql
datadir = /path/to/mysql/data
```

and initialize the database again. Make sure you give `--defaults-file=/path/to/mysql/my.cnf` when you initialize. If you get error saying files exist in `/path/to/mysql/data`, remove them and try again. Once done, when you run mysql also, give `--defaults-file=/path/to/mysql/my.cnf`.
Should work.

Answer (score -3):

Before hitting mysql on command prompt make sure your correct `my.cnf configuration file` is in  placed and set the permission of etc folder as

`chmod -R 777`

etc folder as below list to avoid

> error MySQL - ERROR 2002 (HY000): 
>   e.g /etc/my.cnf, /etc/mysql/my.cnf, $MYSQL_HOME/my.cnf [datadir]/my.cnf ~/.my.cnf

Comment: chmod -R 777 to /etc is never good, this directory has an huge ammount of system files which you don't want to give all permissions like this.