# MySQL stopping and socket file dissapearing

Tags: mysql, mariadb

I am having problems launching `MySQL` on my local machine. Every time I try to launch the instance I get an:

```
ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2 "No such file or directory")
```

For creating the required file I followed [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46071961/8214868) changing the directory `/var/lib/...` to `/var/run/...` since it is how my configuration is set. The weird thing is that when I follow the steps described the process is launched and I can access to my database, but after a while it suddenly stops and the files (mysqld.sock and mysqld.pid) dissappear. **How can this be possible? How can avoid it from happening?**

The settings on my `50-server.cnf` of my `mariadb` are:

```
#
# * Basic Settings
#
user        = mysql
pid-file    = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid
socket      = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
port        = 3306
basedir     = /usr
datadir     = /var/lib/mysql
tmpdir      = /tmp
lc-messages-dir = /usr/share/mysql
skip-external-locking

# Instead of skip-networking the default is now to listen only on
# localhost which is more compatible and is not less secure.
bind-address        = localhost
```

Comment: What version of MariaDB?  Were you 'root' when installing?  What OS?  Is there Aparmor or other?

Comment: The following version `mariadb  Ver 15.1 Distrib 10.1.34-MariaDB` and root user when installing. @RickJames